# Changing auto reply in Outlook from administrator account

Tags: microsoft-outlook, office365

I know how to change my own auto reply, but I have change another users by scheduling access to an admin account. How do I do this so I'm not wasting time looking around?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What permissions does your administrator account have?

If you have the exchange admin account you could run below command to change the oof via admin account:

```
Set-MailboxAutoReplyConfiguration -Identity user@contoso.com -AutoReplyState Enabled -InternalMessage "Internal auto-reply message." -ExternalMessage "External auto-reply message."
```

For more details: [Set-MailboxAutoReplyConfiguration](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/set-mailboxautoreplyconfiguration?view=exchange-ps)

If your admin account only has the permission to access the user's mailbox, you could add the user's mailbox as an additional mailbox and configure oof for this user. Detailed steps for your reference: [How to add a shared mailbox as additional account in Outlook (2022 version)](https://www.michev.info/Blog/Post/3567/how-to-add-a-shared-mailbox-as-additional-account-in-outlook-2022-version) and [Send automatic out of office replies from Outlook](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/send-automatic-out-of-office-replies-from-outlook-9742f476-5348-4f9f-997f-5e208513bd67)